# Can't resolve all parameters for HttpHeaders

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to import and use HttpHeaders to set post headers.
How ever even before using it in code, straight away I'm getting an error in browser runtime (it compiles succesfully in webstorm IDE using ng-cli and ng serve):

```
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HttpHeaders: (?).
```

The only place I'm invoking the class token is in the imports and the app module:

**app.module**

```
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ...
],
  imports: [
  ...
],
providers: [
  Policy,
  ...
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders
],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**GenericHttpService.ts**

```
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
...
@Injectable()
export class GenericHttpService implements IGenericHttp{
   constructor(private _http:HttpClient){

   }
  ...
}
```

These are the only places I have used **HttpHeaders** .
The documentation for HttpHeaders does not say anything about required parameters for HttpHeaders.

Comment: Import `HttpClientModule` instead of providing each of tokens separately

Comment: Tnx I actually forgot this... I had this issue with Http adn HttpModule I guess I should of thought of this. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as yurzui said in the comment to the post, importing HttpClientModule instead of providing each of tokens separately worked and solved this issue.

Comment: I know it's very old but any chance to share how exactly you used 'HttpClientModule'?